# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 9} (\sqrt{x} + 2) = 5$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I'm reviewing some very basic concepts in analysis because I want to get better at it. I am trying to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to 9}(\sqrt{x} + 2) = 5$$
using the rigorous definition of a limit.
Here is my proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. And take $\delta = \epsilon$. Then $\lvert x-9\rvert < \delta$ implies that $\lvert \sqrt{x} + 3\rvert\lvert \sqrt{x} - 3\rvert < \delta$ so that
$$\lvert \sqrt{x} - 3\rvert < \frac{\delta}{\lvert \sqrt{x} + 3\rvert}$$
For sufficiently small $\epsilon$, $\lvert x - 9\rvert < \delta$ implies that $\lvert \sqrt{x} + 3\rvert \geq 1$, meaning
$$\lvert \sqrt{x} - 3\rvert < \frac{\delta}{\lvert \sqrt{x} + 3\rvert} \leq \frac{\delta}{1} = \epsilon$$

Is all of this logically valid? I'm particularly concerned about the part where I say "For sufficiently small $\epsilon$, $\lvert x - 9\rvert < \delta$ implies that $\lvert \sqrt{x} + 3\rvert \geq 1$"

All help and criticism is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: For $|x-9|<9$ we get $x\ge 0.$ Then $\sqrt{x}+3\ge 3.$

Comment: "For sufficiently small $\epsilon$", maybe clarify and mention a bound of $\epsilon$ (by considering for what $x$ is $\sqrt x$ defined). Then choose a different formula of $\delta$ for large $\epsilon$.

Comment: @peterwhy ok, this makes sense to me. What troubles me is that usually in a course where $\epsilon$ neighborhoods come up, only the case where $\epsilon$ being small is considered important, and expressions for sufficient $\delta$ are formulated which don't work for large $\epsilon$. Is this just the gap between what we define rigorously and what we actually care about when arguing something? In the question you linked too, they make an assumption that $\epsilon <1$.

Comment: True that in reality only small $\epsilon$ is considered important. For example here, I may choose $\delta = \epsilon$ for "small" $\epsilon \le 9$, then $\lvert x-9\rvert < \delta \implies \left\lvert\sqrt x-3\right\rvert < \epsilon$. But what about "large" $\epsilon > 9$? Pick a "small" $\delta$ ($=9$ for example) and reuse the same argument: $\lvert x-9\rvert < 9 = \delta \implies \left\lvert\sqrt x-3\right\rvert < 9 < \epsilon$.

Comment: So to be rigorous and in practice, let $\epsilon' = \min(\epsilon, 9)$, then follow your same proof to pick $\delta = \epsilon'$.